# Can't write the content to a file using rpc xml

Tags: php

I have some content which I want to write to a file called `bk_strategy-ptr-to-real-file.h`. Here is the code:

```
echo $content = $header.$parameters.$footer;

$myFile = "/home/vikas/hft/common/internal/config/trader/master/bk_strategy-ptr-to-real-file.h";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
```

Is this possible to write a file using xml rpc?

Answer (score 0):

You don't write to files using xml-rpc, it is a communications protocol. You use your php or asp to write the files. What you have is fine:

```
$myFile = "/home/vikas/hft/common/internal/config/trader/master/bk_strategy-ptr-to-real-file.h";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $content);
fclose($fh);
```

But why is the file a .h extension, should it not be .xml, or maybe .txt or .php depending on what you want to do with the response next.

Comment: its extension file is .h beacause its a header file in c programming language.